# Return more counts for same field

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Given the following document:

```js
[
  {
    "user": "A",
    "feedback":"like"
  },
  {
    "user": "B",
    "feedback":"dislike"
  },
  {
    "user": "C",
    "feedback":"like"
  },
  {
    "user": "D",
    "feedback":"like"
  },
  {
    "user": "E",
    "feedback":"dislike"
  },
]
```

I would like to get likes count and dislikes count.

In this case I would get `{likesCount: 3, dislikesCount: 2}`.

How can I achieve this using Mongoose?

Answer (score 2):

Query

- assuming that feedback and only be one of those 2 values
- group by null (all collection 1 group)
  (null is a common choice, the point is to group by a constant
  `"_id" : "hello"` would do the same)
- and 2 sums, if its like add to likesCount 1, else add 0
  (the same for the dislikes)

[Playmongo](https://cmql.org/playmongo/?q=62ae01af91b564fc1e7e95a9)

```js
yourColl.aggregate(
[{"$group": 
   {"_id": null,
    "likesCount": 
     {"$sum": {"$cond": [{"$eq": ["$feedback", "like"]}, 1, 0]}},
    "dislikesCount": 
     {"$sum": {"$cond": [{"$eq": ["$feedback", "dislike"]}, 1, 0]}}}}])
```